# I am trying to get google place details info like website,phone etc

Tags: android

I am trying to get google place details info like website,phone etc my code is work perfect but some time dose not display data but logcat to display response.
Use this url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/detai/json?placeid="place id"&key="api key"

pls help me..

Comment: What you want excatly???

Comment: display place details....

Answer (score 0):

A Place Details request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?parameters

where output may be either of the following values:

- json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
- xml indicates output as XML

Here is the Query URL :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: see my url :  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJFa58xmFO4DsRgN0RY_2WBVQ&key=AIzaSyDzISbPUIu4rH3SSQ6vtWt3zzvUCiMIcU4

Comment: @RameshPrajapati do you have the status code or error code in response when the data is not shown?

Comment: @RameshPrajapati can you try to reproduce the issue? also can you test it in postman tool?